# How can Google's own MapsActivity result in a ClassNotFoundException on a Samsung phone?

Tags: android, android-activity, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps

I got the strangest error in my Google Play Console yesterday.

I have a button that opens up directions in the Google Map app. Had it for years. Looks like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&daddr=" +
                    lat + "," + lon));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Yesterday i got this error log:

```
Samsung Galaxy J6+ (j6primelte), Android 8.1
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:
```

I cannot for the world understand how this can happen, and i have never seen it before. Anyone knows more than me?

**EDIT:** Obviously i know that i can put a try/catch around it. That's not my question. I wondered how it is possible, on a Samsung, to get a ActivityNotFound on something in the google maps API. Only thing i can think of is a rooted phone?

This button floats on top of a Google map, and we check for google play services when app is started, so you can't get to this point unless you are already seeing a Google map in the app.

Comment: Is you Google Play Services up to date? Did you disable it by accident?

Comment: @Mathias Your phone have google map application?

Comment: this means that `com.google.android.apps.maps` package (Google Maps app) is not installed on the device. Yes, that is possible. Not all devices have it installed by default.

Comment: Hi guys. Yeah, it absolutely seems to not be installed. BUT we check for existence of google play service whenever app is started, and how can it NOT be installed on a Samsung phone? This is basically what bothers me. It's a "directions" button on top of a map, so you couldn't even get there in our app unless a Google map is already showing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Able to show a Google map" and "the Google Maps app is installed" are not the same thing.  Clearly your user has Play Services installed (used to embed a map in your app), but not Google Maps.  Presumably he or she has rooted the phone and installed a different ROM that doesn't have Google Maps.  Generally (as you can now see) it's not a good idea to assume anything about what apps will be installed on a phone in the wild.

Here's my code to check for it:

```
public void showDirections(String address, FragmentActivity activity) {

    address = Uri.encode(address);
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" + address);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

    if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) == null) {
        DialogUtils.getInstance(activity).reportError(activity, "Google Maps is required for this feature");
        return;
    }

    activity.startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i kind of came to that conclusion also. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure put your code in,

```
try {

    //Put your code here

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Because when you set intent to open specific application maybe that application is **not install** in that device (in your case Samsung phone), so that below calss not found and it **throws exception.**

```
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```